# Simple Text Editor using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am interested in developing a  text editor application using Jetpack Compose that enables users to  insert both text and tables and image, similar to Google Docs.If I use a TextField as the editor then how can i implement the editable table and image insertion feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `textField` Composable you have to make **your own custom text editor**.

A Good start would be checking others projects on the same topic i could recommend the [Compose Rich Editor by MohamedRejeb](https://github.com/MohamedRejeb/Compose-Rich-Editor)